# How to Connect two qml files?

Tags: qml

I am making a music player application. i have a DownRect which has a slider and a playSection which has a button. this button has a audio. when button is clicked audio is played and i want the slider to set it's value by the audio duration. (the button is add dynamically from ButtonD.qml file). what i want to do is to connect DownRect's slider to playSection's button.

```
//DownRect.qml
Rectangle{
    id: downRectangle
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    x:0
    y:750
    color: "#c62828"
    smooth: true
Slider{

        id: sliderDownRect
        x: 300
        y: 25
        width: 650
        from: 0
        //        to: play.duration
        stepSize: 100
        value: 0
        Material.accent : Material.background
        Material.foreground: Material.background
        onValueChanged:{

        }

    }
}
```

and here is the ButtonD.qml file which i'd like to connect to DownRect.qml

```
  //ButtonD.qml
Button{
    id: buttonD
    width:900
    height: 46
    flat: true
  Audio{
        id: playing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You make sure that the duration (and other relevant properties of `Audio`) are exposed in `ButtonD.qml`, e.g. by adding aliases like such:

```
Button {
    id: buttonD
    property alias duration: playing.duration
    ...
}
```

The same goes for the `Slider`'s value.

```
Rectangle {
    id: downRectangle
    property alias duration: sliderDownRect.to
    ...
}
```

In the file that instantiates both, you use `Binding`-objects to create a bidirectional binding between the both. Those `Binding`-objects excell at working with dynamically instantiated objects.

Basically, if you'd include the files into one file, this should look something like this:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.5

ApplicationWindow {
    id: myWindow
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 600
    color: 'white'

    property Item dynamicallyCreatedItem

    Button {
        x: 102
        text: 'create'
        onClicked: {
            dynamicallyCreatedItem = Qt.createComponent('AudioButton.qml').createObject(myWindow.contentItem)
        }
    }

    DownRect {
        y: 50
        id: rect
    }


    Binding {
        target: rect
        property: 'maxValue'
        value: dynamicallyCreatedItem ? dynamicallyCreatedItem.duration : 0
        when: dynamicallyCreatedItem
    }

    Binding {
        target: rect
        property: 'value'
        value: dynamicallyCreatedItem ? dynamicallyCreatedItem.position : 0
        when: dynamicallyCreatedItem
    }
}
```

**AudioButton.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.5

Button {
    id: audioButton
    onClicked: audio.play()
    property alias duration: audio.duration
    property alias position: audio.position
    Audio {
        id: audio
        source: 'airhorn.wav'
    }
}
```

**DownRect.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: rect
    width: parent.width
    height: 50
    property alias value: slider.value
    property alias maxValue: slider.to
    Slider {
        id: slider
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay i added @Binding {target: ButtonD; property: "playing"; value: duration;}@ to the slider but slider's value is always at max - i mean i want it  to be the second of the audio which is playing

Comment: `duration` is how long the sound is. So you should bind the `Slider`'s `to` to it. The current time is probably [`position`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-audio.html#position-prop) - so bind `Audio.duration` -> `Slider.to` and `Audio.position` -> `Slider.value`

Comment: i wrote @    property alias position: playing.position
    property alias duration: playing.duration@ in ButtonD and @   property alias duration: sliderDownRect.to
    property alias position: sliderDownRect.value@ in DownRect and @        Binding {target: ButtonD; property: "playing"; value: duration;}
        Binding{target:ButtonD; property: "playing"; value: position; }@ in Slider in DownRect but nothing happens

Comment: It might be, that your sound is to short (<1second)? The `position` is by default only updated every 1000ms.  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-audio.html#notifyInterval-prop - You can change this starting Qt5.9

Comment: You've got the `target` in your bindings wrong. You set the `Button`'s duration (which should come from the audio file) to the `to`-value of the `Slider` rather than the other way around.

Comment: where i should define bindings? (ButtonD.qml or DownRect.qml)

Comment: In neither of them. In the file, where you use both, ButtonD.qml and DownRect.qml. If you'd share, how you dynamically instantiate `ButtonD`, I could show you the rest.

Comment: i use javascript to add button. there is a button and when i press it the code in the below link is called: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html

Comment: okay - i used the code you've suggested and i gives me the error: QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
why?

Comment: The line `Qt.createComponent('AudioButton.qml').createObject(myWindow.contentItem)` is to slow, and the `createObject` is called before the component is ready. See the 3. code block [**here**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html#creating-objects-dynamically) and the explaination to it.